# Problems with reading MOBI documens from Aldiko on Kindle

Tags: kindle, mobi

I've used once handy to read e-books and I've used some app called Aldiko, that was downloading e-books in MOBI format.

After buying Kindle I've copied them into it, but when I try to open it, the book is opened on the end (at about 98%) and I can't navigate to first site. Navigating to 'begin' moves me to that 98%...

So it seems that the MOBI document is in some way 'broken' so that Kindle can't read it correctly. Is it possible to 'fix' it? And what can cause such incompatibilites?

Answer (score 1):

How did you manage to get those books to your kindle? By cable or by email? If cable I would try to send them over your kindle mail - it will got parsed one more time and that could help.

Comment: It was by the cable... is it possible that those e-books are somehow 'blocked' to be read only by Aldiko app?

Comment: Aldiko could change something in the files that may prevent them work properly on Kindle. If you send those eBooks through your kindle email address there is a chance that amazon will fix them in that process. More you can read here: http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/?nodeId=200767340

Comment: OK I'll check that option. I never intended to use Kindle 'interactively' so I've disabled WiFi the first day and I don't know where my kindle e-mail is... well, I have to start searching...